# How to put a comment after a IPython magic command

Tags: ipython, ipython-magic

How can I put a comment at the end of an [IPython magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)?

Eg, trying to use [`%cd`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd):

```
%cd "dir"  # comment
```

I want to change to directory `dir` but instead I get:

> ```
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dir # comment'
> ```

Comment: Some magics appear to work with a comment, but this `cd` does not.  I don't see an indication in the docs or other wise as to why there's a difference.  If a `magic` takes flagged options, those strings are parsed either directly or by an `argparse` like parser.  `%cd??` may be give further clues as to why it ignores the `#` comment character.

Comment: @hpaulj `%cd??` doesn't help. Have updated question with doco link.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in general because IPython magic commands parse their own command lines.*

There are some magic commands where comments *seem to work*, but actually they're being handled in another way. For example:

- `%ls # comment` works properly, but `%ls` is an alias to a shell command, so the shell is what's parsing the comment.
- `%automagic 0 # comment` behaves like `%automagic`, toggling the setting instead of exclusively disabling it like `%automagic 0` would do. It's as if the `0 # comment` is all one string, which it ignores.
- `%run $filename # comment` treats the comment as arguments, so `['#', 'comment']` ends up in `sys.argv` for `$filename`.

---

#### Workaround

You could call magic commands using exclusively Python syntax.

First get the running IPython instance with [`get_ipython()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.getipython.html#IPython.core.getipython.get_ipython):

```
ipython = get_ipython()
```

Then:

```
ipython.run_line_magic('cd', 'dir')  # comment
```

- Docs: [`InteractiveShell.run_line_magic()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.run_line_magic)

Or for cell magics, you could go from this (which doesn't work):

```
%%script bash  # comment
echo hello
```

to this:

```
ipython.run_cell_magic('script', 'bash', 'echo hello')  # comment
```

- Docs: [`InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic)

Another option, I suppose, is to run an entire cell, although, suppressing the output since it returns an `ExecutionResult` object:

```
ipython.run_cell('%cd dir');  # comment
```

- Docs: [`InteractiveShell.run_cell()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.run_cell)

---

* *I'm not sure if this is documented explicitly, but it is documented implicitly under [defining custom magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html#defining-custom-magics), and I found the clues in this GitHub issue: [Allow comments after arguments in magic_arguments](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13012).*

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: You cannot as things stand. This might or might not be an error in the implementation of `%cd`.

Until this is fixed, one way to avoid this is to use:

```
import os
os.chdir("dir") #some comment here
```

A second alternative is using bash commands.
However `%` is a magic command, not equivalent to a bash command. This is on purpose,
as it can change **the current directory of the notebook**.

This is not the same as e.g.

```
!cd dir #some comment here
```

Which will spawn a shell and execute the command there thus not changing the current directory. (You can verify using `pwd` before/after each command)

Note that if your goal is not to change the current jupyter notebook directory, you can issue multiple commands in one cell with the magic
`%sh`:

```
%%sh 
cd dir #some comment here
ls #some more commands here
....
```

This command will spawn a shell and all bash commands will be executed there, so the current jupyter directory will not change.

Comment: `os.chdir()` is not really a replacement for `%cd`. For example, `%cd` on its own works and goes to your home directory, while `os.chdir()` on its own throws an error, `missing required argument 'path'`. `%cd` also supports tilde as a shorthand for your home directory, like for example, `%cd ~/projects`.

Comment: Sorry, why are you talking about shell commands? That's not what OP's asking about.

Comment: True, the OP is asking How to put a comment after a IPython magic command. The TL;DR answer is you can't until/unless %cd is fixed.

Comment: `%cd` can be replaced by the much less elegant (but still working if the notebook is ever converted/used to just python ) `os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~'))` ; so does `%cd ~/projects` correspond to `os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/projects'))` It's up to you and your aesthetics if you'll go for this option or just skip / place the comments somewhere else, both are imperfect, please don't shoot the messenger:)

Comment: But the problem also isn't specific to `%cd`... For example, `%%script` is also affected, and there's no drop-in replacement for that as far as I know. *Although*, I posted a comment with maybe a better workaround: `ipython = get_ipython()` then `ipython.run_line_magic('cd', 'dir')  # comment`. Or for cell magics, `ipython.run_cell_magic('script', 'bash', 'echo hello')  # comment`. By all means put this in your answer if you want.

Comment: Those were just two examples and I know it's possible to replicate them in plain Python, but `%cd` has more capabilities, like `%cd -` to go to the previous WD and `%cd $foobar` to use a Python variable `foobar`. So it'd be better to use the `run_*_magic()` functions like I mentioned.

Comment: BTW, careful, [sh is not the same thing as Bash](/q/5725296/4518341).

Comment: Also, maybe this is nitpicking, but what makes you say it's an error in the implementation? I don't think the IPython documentation says how comments work with magic commands, so this seems like undefined behaviour if anything. And I found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13012) where the discussion implies this is the behaviour the implementers intended, even if it's not documented.

Comment: It could be by design. The reason I am supposing this is that  other commands seem to be taking comments ok... e.g. one can do `%ls .. . #comment`. Also I think I did a small search at the time I answered this and there were other people believing this - I dont remember finding something concrete though. What is your opinion on the matter?

Comment: Hmm... `%ls` isn't *really* a magic command, it's an alias for a shell command. So the comment would be parsed by the shell, I suppose. BTW, there are other real magic commands that seem to allow comments, but actually they're just handling them other ways. For example, `%automagic 0 # comment` behaves like `%automagic`, as if the `0 # comment` is all one string, which it ignores. Ultimately, I guess the problem is that magics parse their own command lines.

Comment: I opted to post my own answer. Thanks for spurring that :) I learned some stuff about IPython along the way while trying to figure out how this actually works.